# New Payload type for RTP profile

Tags: format, types, packet, rtp, payload

I am designing a new RTP profile. How can I determine the next available RTP payload type, which I can assign to my profile type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IANA is the entity that oversees, among the other symbols, RTP payload type. You can find the list of already assigned RTP payload types here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/rtp-parameters.

Note however that registering static payload types is now considered a deprecated practice in favor of dynamic payload type negotiation. Dynamic payload types use the range 96 to 127. They are assigned by means outside of the RTP profile or protocol specification. For more details please refer to http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/rtp/faq.html#pt-dynamic.